# CSV one column bad encoded. Can't pandas.read_csv

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a CSV file that contains several columns. One of those columns is corrupted, bad encoded.
The column named `title` has characters of all kinds of languages: French, Italy, etc...

```
num | ratio |  title   | ...
 1     1.2     ðŸ¥¶2ï
 2     2.5     djije
 3     4.1     abc
...    ...     ...
```

When I try to read the file `pandas.read_csv('myFile.csv')` I receive the following error:

```
'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xcf in position 3: invalid continuation byte
```

How can I read the csv file with `pandas` and leaving the title column blank or giving it some default value if it can't be read?

Answer (score 0):

If your file contains mixed encodings, you can read it into memory as binary, or as a hack, open it as Latin-1 and then decode the *Title* field individually on each line.

If the majority of the data is encoded as UTF-8, you can attempt to decode it with

```
title.encode('latin-1').decode('utf-8 )
```

but fall back and keep it in Latin-1, or replace it with some sort of error message, if decoding fails.

I'm not a Pandas person, but quick googling gets me something like

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('myFile.csv', encoding='latin-1')

def attempt_decode(x):
    try:
        return x.encode('latin-1').decode('utf-8')
    except UnicodeDecodeError:
        return 'Unable to decode: %s' % x)

df['Title'] = df['Title'].apply(attempt_decode)
```

Latin-1 has the unique property that every input byte corresponds exactly to the Unicode code point with the same value, so you never get a decoding error (but, obviously, [mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake) if the correct encoding is something else, and you fail to correct it).

Answer (score -1):

If you want to exclude the column `title` alone, read all the columns and drop the column `title`.

Eg.

```py
df = pd.read_csv('filename')

df = data.drop('title', axis = 1)
```

To give the column a default value, use:

```py
df['title'] = 0 #(the value you want to provide by default)
```

or use:

```py
df['title'] = np.nan
```

to fill the column with null values.

Hope that answers your question!

Comment: But the problem is that they can't read it in the first place, isn't it?

Comment: Sorry true, so the only workaround would be to delete the column or do the proper encoding.